# If Count is over _ amount, and FileName does NOT contain _

Tags: excel, vba, instr

I'm looking to construct my IF, Then, Else statement to deal with all possible occurrences in my reports.

- If the number of occurrences of a variable (fCount) is over 6 and the Filename (fName) does NOT contain the string "RADMON", then save the report.
- If the number of occurrences of a variable (fCount) is over 249 and the Filename (fName) DOES contain the string "RADMON", then save the report.
- If neither is true, then Kill the report.

I currently structure it like this:

```vb
If fCount > 6 And Not InStr(1, fName, "RADMON", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
    ActiveWorkbook.Save 
ElseIf InStr(1, fName, "RADMON", vbTextCompare) = 0 And fCount >= 250 Then 
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Kill
```

The result is that is that reports where the fCount is over 6 but fName does not contain "RADMON" are being actively killed by my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first if statement is a double negative.  The [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function will return the position of the found string.  `InStr(1, fName, "RADMON", vbTextCompare) = 0` would mean that the string wasn't found, having `Not InStr(1, fName, "RADMON", vbTextCompare) = 0` is saying if `fCount` is greater than 6 and "RADMON" was found, save the file.

```
If fCount > 6 And InStr(1, fName, "RADMON", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
  ActiveWorkbook.Save 
ElseIf InStr(1, fName, "RADMON", vbTextCompare) > 0 And fCount >= 250 Then 
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
Else
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
  Kill
End if
```

Comment: I'm certain this is correct.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: @CaptMAZing if this solved your problem please mark the answer as solved.